# can't read the property title of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Basically I was trying to `console log` the title of the to-do from the `json- placeholder`, but I get the error shown at the end:

Here is my .js file:

```
//starts at 14:43, sat 21/9/2019

//jsonph

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=3';

async function getDataFromCinemasAPI() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    //FIXME: da undefined
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[title]);              
    }
}

getDataFromCinemasAPI();

$('.card-text.c1').html()`
```

Here is the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: title is not defined
>       at getDataFromCinemasAPI

Comment: try `console.log(data.title);`

Comment: As the error says. There's no variable with name `title` in your script: `data[title]` -> `data["title"]` / `data.title`

Comment: `title` should be a string and reference an element in your array `console.log(data[i]["title"]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, use square bracket notation or dot notation. However the other problem you had is that `data` is an array, which you're looping over so you needed `data[i]["title"]` or `data[i].title`

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=3';

async function getDataFromCinemasAPI() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    //FIXME: da undefined
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i]["title"]);
    }
}

getDataFromCinemasAPI();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a property whose name you know before run-time you should **`object.property`** (You can also use **`object["property"]`**, though it's not recommended). If you are trying to get a property whose name you only know at run-time then you should use **`object[propertyName]`** (where propertyName is a variable).

In the code you have supplied you are using `data[title]`, so you should replace it with `data.title` (or `data["title"]`).

But the json you have supplied contains an array of objects instead of one object, so you should first get the item at that index **`data[i]`** and then get the title property **`data[i].title`**.

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=3';

async function getDataFromCinemasAPI() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].title);
  }
}

getDataFromCinemasAPI();
```

Answer (score 0):

data is an array, so you have to access the position of the element before print a property

```
console.log(data[i].title)
```

Answer (score 0):

done! with `console.log(data[i]["title"]);` thanks Nick Parsons!